# HOW do I make glossy effect on label?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, shaders

I've used the fresnel and glossy shaders but either I get a grey and dull effect or a diffused look when I render. I want to make the label look like plastic wrap so I need some streaks of light reflected off the bottle but the bottom label isn't cooperating. I then tried the top label and that one did just fine even tho I used the same node setup as the one below. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe don't use a Fresnel, or put a second Mix with the Fresnel but before that keep a Mix with Diffuse and Glossy and play with the mix value

Comment: should be easier to see changes if you use an HDRi as a background. Will produce realistic lighting and more variation on the reflections.

Comment: Use a single BSDF Principled Shader instead of two shaders and fresnel.